# Stored Procedure if condition not working MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

> (Using MySQL Database from Amazon RDS)

**Procedure** *signup*

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`communitybd`@`%` PROCEDURE `signup`(
    fullname VARCHAR(254), 
    phone VARCHAR(20),
    email VARCHAR(254),
    pass VARCHAR(254)
    )
    BEGIN
    DECLARE output int;

    IF (SELECT COUNT(fullname) FROM users WHERE email = email or phone = phone) >= 1 THEN
        SET output = 0;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO users(`fullname`,`phone`,`email`,`password`,`createdat`) 
          VALUES(fullname,phone, email, pass,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());
        SET output =  1; 
    END IF;
    SELECT output;
    END
```

**Calling**

```
CALL `communitybd`.`signup`('Himel Rana', '+8801966584755', 'another@himelrana-swe.com', 'password111');
```

it works for 1st time only. But when I am trying to add another user with different phone and email it returning `0` it should return `1`
Can you please help me why if condition not working? 
I already tried using `if exists` not working too

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question because when I am writing this problem suddenly I have solved this.

> We should mention table name in query

This line:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(fullname) FROM users WHERE email = email or phone = phone) >= 1 THEN
```

should be like below:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(fullname) FROM users WHERE users.email = email or users.phone = phone) >= 1 THEN
```

***Hope this will help other people who make mistake like this.***